# Efficiently remove file(s) from large .tgz

Tags: tar, gzip

Assume i have an gzip compressed tar-ball compressedArchive.tgz (+100 files, totaling +5gb).

What would be the fastest way to remove all entries matching a given filename pattern for example prefix*.jpg and then store the remains in a gzip:ed tar-ball again?

Replacing the old archive or creating a new one is not important, whichever is fastest.

Comment: Related: [How can I filter the contents of a tar file, producing another tar file in the pipe?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224835)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With GNU `tar`, you can do:

```
pigz -d < file.tgz |
  tar --delete --wildcards -f - '*/prefix*.jpg' |
  pigz > newfile.tgz
```

With `bsdtar`:

```
pigz -d < file.tgz |
  bsdtar -cf - --exclude='*/prefix*.jpg' @- |
  pigz > newfile.tgz
```

(`pigz` being the multi-threaded version of `gzip`).

You could overwrite the file over itself like:

```
{ pigz -d < file.tgz |
    tar --delete --wildcards -f - '*/prefix*.jpg' |
    pigz &&
    perl -e 'truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT'
} 1<> file.tgz
```

But that's quite risky, especially if the result ends up being less compressed than the original file (in which case, the second `pigz` may end up overwriting areas of the file which the first one has not read yet).

Comment: thanks for the answer, upvoted. will run benchmark next week to see which one performs better for my archive and system and accept that.

Answer (score 10):

Don't discount the easy way: it may be fast enough for your purpose. With [avfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18118/how-can-i-view-the-contents-of-a-tar-gz-file-filenames-filesize/18167#18167) to access the archive as a directory:

```
cd ~/.avfs/path/to/original.tar.gz\#
pax -w -s '/^.*\.jpg$//' | gzip >/path/to/filtered.tar.gz        # POSIX
tar -czf /path/to/filtered.tar.gz -s '/^.*\.jpg$//' .            # BSD
tar -czf /path/to/filtered.tar.gz --transform '/^.*\.jpg$//' .   # GNU
```

With more primitive tools, first extract the files excluding the `.jpg` files, then create a new archive.

```
mkdir tmpdir && cd tmpdir
<original.tar.gz gzip -d | pax -r -pe -s '/^.*\.jpg$//'
pax -w . | gzip >filtered.tar.gz
cd .. && rm -rf tmpdir
```

If your tar has `--exclude`:

```
mkdir tmpdir && cd tmpdir
tar -xzf original.tar.gz --exclude='*.jpg'
tar -czf filtered.tar.gz .
cd .. && rm -rf tmpdir
```

This may however mangle file ownership and modes if you don't run it as root. For best results, use a temporary directory on a fast filesystem — tmpfs if you have one that's large enough.

Support for archivers to act as a pass-through (i.e read an archive and write an archive) tends to be limited. [GNU tar can delete members from an archive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80239/efficiently-remove-files-from-large-tgz/80252#80252) with the [`--delete` operation option](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/operations.html#SEC64) (“The `--delete` option has been reported to work properly when `tar` acts as a filter from `stdin` to `stdout`.”), and that's probably your best option.

You can make powerful archive filters in a few lines of Python. Its [`tarfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) library can read and write from non-seekable streams, and you can use arbitrary code in Python to filter, rename, modify…

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re, sys, tarfile
source = tarfile.open(fileobj=sys.stdin, mode='r|*')
dest = tarfile.open(fileobj=sys.stdout, mode='w|gz')
for member in source:
    if not (member.isreg() and re.match(r'.*\.jpg\Z', member.name)):
        sys.stderr.write(member.name + '\n')
        dest.addfile(member, source.extractfile(member))
dest.close()
```

Comment: It would also mangle uid/usernames if run as root unless it is done on a machine that has the same uid <=> username mapping as the one where the tar file was initially created. ACLs, extended attributes may be affected  as well. With `tar`, you may  want to add the `p` option.

Answer (score 2):

With the tar that comes on Mac OSX, you could do this:

```
tar -czf b.tgz --exclude '*.jpg' @a.tgz
mv b.tgz a.tgz
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you probably have to extract all the contenent of .tgz file in a local dir then erase the files you do not want then recompress the .tgz.

It's long and you need sufficent free disk space but to the best of my knowledge, there is non other way to do it.

Given that you already have some path like `/tmpdir/withalotofspace` that have sufficent free space (check it using  `df -h /tmpdir/withalotofspace`),  you can do something like this:

```
$ cd /tmpdir/withalotofspace
$ tar -xvfz /path/to/compressedArchive.tgz
$ find /tmpdir/withalotofspace/ -type f -iname '*.jpg' -delete
$ tar -cvzf /path/to/purgedcompressedArchive.tgz .
```

Comment: As the other answers show, through piping there is no need to store uncompressed data on the disk at any point

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
tar -xvf myLarge.gz --exclude "prefix" | tar -czvf myLarge.gz -T -
```

This will:

1. Extract all files except files including "**prefix**"
2. (`-T -`) Pipe rest to tar and re-compress myLarge.gz

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer by @Gilles, except it can be further simplified.  After unzipping, for example `gunzip foo.tgz` the file will be `foo.tar` and files can be removed with `tar -f foo.tar --delete file|directory`.  Below is an example of removing a directory from a tar file.

```
    phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~/Downloads$ tar -cvf moo.tar moo1/
    moo1/
    moo1/moo2/
    moo1/moo2/moo3/
    moo1/moo2/moo3/moo4/
    moo1/moo2/moo3/moo4/moo5/
    phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~/Downloads$ tar -tf moo.tar 
    moo1/
    moo1/moo2/
    moo1/moo2/moo3/
    moo1/moo2/moo3/moo4/
    moo1/moo2/moo3/moo4/moo5/
    phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~/Downloads$ tar -f moo.tar --delete "moo1/moo2/moo3"
    phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~/Downloads$ tar -tf moo.tar 
    moo1/
    moo1/moo2/
```

Specific file types can be found with `tar -tf foo.tar|egrep -i '.jpg$'`.