# Read concatenated output of tgz archive (with plain text files), with filenames, without unpacking in bash?

Tags: tar, less, gzip

I have a bunch of text files/logs, which I'd like to pack into a gzipped tar archive, say:

```
cd /tmp
echo "My Content One" > aaa.log
echo "My Content OneA" >> aaa.log
echo "My Content Two" > bbb.log
echo "My Content TwoB" >> bbb.log
tar czvf test.tgz *.log
```

Now, if I open this with `less test.tgz`, I get a listing of files same as `tar tzvf test.tgz` would give me:

```
-rw-rw-r-- user/user 31 2017-10-29 03:10 aaa.log
-rw-rw-r-- user/user 31 2017-10-29 03:10 bbb.log
```

First, I found https://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3798511/Reading-Compressed-Files-With-less.htm, and tried setting up in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
 alias tgzless='LESSOPEN="|tar --to-stdout -zxf %s" less'
```

Now I can do `tgzless test.tgz`, and this prints the concatenated contents of all files:

```
My Content One
My Content OneA
My Content Two
My Content TwoB
```

... but unfortunately doesn't print the filenames, so I don't really know which part belongs where.

Then, I found [How can i view the contents of a tar.gz file (filenames + filesize)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18118/how-can-i-view-the-contents-of-a-tar-gz-file-filenames-filesize), and tried this command:

```
gzip -dc test.tgz | less
```

Now, this will print both a file heading, and the content of the file - unfortunately the file heading is binary and difficult to read - it looks something like this inside `less`:

```
aaa.log^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@0000664^@0001750^@0001750^@00000000037^@131752
34246^@014636^@ 0^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ustar  
^@user^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@user^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@My Content One
My Content OneA
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
...
```

... so it is hard to read (note that `gzip -dc test.tgz | tar -tf - | less` gives just a listing of filenames, though less verbose one than `tar tzvf`)

So can I set up an alias somehow using these standard commands, that would print all filename contents in a tar.gz archive, such that first the filename of the file is printed (preferably in `tar tzvf` format, with username, permission and timestamp), and then its contents?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you’re using [GNU `tar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-an-External-Program.html#SEC87), create a file named `tarcat` on your path with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Permissions user/group size date time name
printf "%s %s/%s %7d %s %s\n" "${TAR_MODE}" "${TAR_UNAME}" "${TAR_GNAME}" "${TAR_SIZE}" "$(date -d @${TAR_ATIME})" "${TAR_FILENAME}"

exec cat
```

Then run `tar x --to-command=tarcat -f test.tgz | less`:

```
0664 user/user      31 Sun 29 Oct 03:10:00 UTC 2017 aaa.log
My Content One
My Content OneA
0664 user/user      31 Sun 29 Oct 03:10:00 UTC 2017 bbb.log
My Content Two
My Content TwoB
```

Decoding the octal file mode and adapting the date/time output is left as an exercise for the reader.